# Two pages have different session_id's

Tags: php, session, sessionid

On page1 i start a session and set `$_SESSION['user']=$user` . When i then echo $user on page1 it echoes correctly.

```
 session_start();
 echo session_id();
 $_SESSION['email'] = $user;
 echo $user;
```

However when i then go to my page2 and run the code

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['email'];
echo session_id();
echo $_SESSION['email'];
```

it does not echo `$_SESSION['email']`
and echoes and different `session_id()`. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Can you look at the request and the value of the `PHPSESSID` cookie? Does it change? Also, make sure you're not blocking cookies.

Comment: There is no way that you could echo $user and get a result. $user is not set in example 1. What sets $user?

Comment: You don't need to call session['email'] and also echo it. Check the network tab and see what is being passed in the session variable, you may just not have it set or you may have reset it somewhere along the way

Comment: @JayBlanchard my $user variable is set before. It works correctly.

Comment: Where is it set? Because you're not setting it with `$_SESSION['user'] = $user;` You're setting `$_SESSION['user']`

Comment: @rivtracks pressing F12 will usually open the lets call it 'developer' tool that will allow you to see what variable is being passed

Comment: Are both pages in same domain ?

Comment: @CoderDojo I realize i don't have to it was just a test to make sure it worked

Comment: Both pages are in the same domain

Comment: different session ID's = different sessions, which almost always means you've got a session cookie problem and the cookie set for the first script isn't available for the second script - usually it's the cookie path breaking things.

Comment: @MarcB how would u suggest i fix that?

Comment: I don't know what "u" would say. I'm not "u". http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php